# How to animate this javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, animation

I have a function that does that if I click on a div-box called "bokse1", margin to a different box called "Whole" will be removed by, in this case, 50px. I want to animate the removal of margin.

here's the function:

```
     $(function() {
   $('#bokse1').click(function() {
     $('#Whole').css('margin-left', '-=50px');
   });
   });
```

I would like the animation to be linear and so it goes for let's say 1 second.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1cybw0ez/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .animate() instead of .css()

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

You can read more about it [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Ok I finally made it work. Thank you, you helped. Also, here's the end result if you wonder: http://jsfiddle.net/1cybw0ez/4/

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use [css's transition](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for setting animation by css

Comment: But how do I connect it with the javascript function? I don't know, and I can't figure it out :(

Comment: It mostly depends on your issue, but in the simplest case you have to setup transition in css, and change value of e.g margin by javascript. Other things browser will do for you. Css transitions has some limitations, but can really help do simple things with minimal coding.